# Racket exchanging first and third elements of a list in a function?

Tags: list, function, racket

Suppose, I got a list(s) in Racket of:

`(1 2 3)

`(1 2 3 4)

`((1 2) (3) (4)))

Then when I exchange it (first and third element), it will look like:

`(3 2 1)

`(3 2 1 4)

`((4) (3) (1 2))

**Please note: I may only use things such as cons, first, and rest for this.**

Here's my current try:

```
(define new-list
(lambda(list)
  (first (rest (rest list))))) ; Get third element.
```

I cannot replicate the results above. I would like to be shown how it's done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just play with it a little:

```
> '(one)
'(one)
> '(one two three)
'(one two three)
> (first '(one two three four))
'one
> (rest '(one two three four))
'(two three four)
> (define foo (lambda (lst)
    (cons (first lst) (rest lst))))
> (foo '(one two three four))
'(one two three four)
> (define bar (lambda (lst)
    (cons (first (rest lst))
          (cons (first lst) (rest lst)))))
> (bar '(one two three four))
'(two one two three four)
```

Now you have everything to complete the process.

Comment: Hey, I am needing your help. I am very close to the answer, I got (define a '(1 2 3)), and I tried (cons (first (rest (rest a))) (cons (first (rest a)) '(1))) as you can see I have to put the 1 there, but I cannot do that. How can I use the variable a instead? Could you help me or have ideas? I have been trying for a long time now!

Comment: you can put `(rest (rest (rest (rest a))))` there ,only perhaps not so many `rest`s. :)

Comment: for instance, have you tried `(cons (first a) (rest a))`?  `(cons (first a) (rest (rest a)))`?  `(cons (first a) (rest (rest (rest a))))`? Have you tried `(cons 2 (cons 3 (cons 1 (rest a))))`? `(cons 2 (cons 3 (cons 1 (rest (rest a)))))`?  `(cons 2 (cons 3 (cons 1 (rest (rest (rest a))))))`? yes using naked 2 is forbidden for you, but can you get to it with one of `(first a)` `(first (rest a))` `(first (rest (rest a)))` `(first (rest (rest (rest a))))`?

Comment: I got it now!

I used one of your snippets above and inserted it into my current statement and got:

(cons (first (rest (rest list))) (cons (first (rest list)) (cons (first list) (rest (rest (rest list))))))))

It hit the nail right on the head!

Thanks!

Comment: great news. it was fun, wasn't it. "just play with it!" is a good attitude to have. :)

Answer (score 2):

To write your procedure, we want to take an input list `xs`, and construct a new list like

```
(cons (third-element xs)
      (cons (second-element xs)
            (cons (first-element xs)
                  (everything-except-the-first-three-elements xs)))
```

In racket you have `car` and `cdr`, but you also have `cadr`, `caddr`, `cddddr` and [everything in betweeen](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28part._.Pair_.Accessor_.Shorthands%29).

To get an intuition for them, `a` reads the head, `d` reads the tail, so

- `car` gets the head (the first element in a list)
- `cdr` gets the tail (everything except the first element in a list)
- `cadr` gets the head of the tail (the second element in a list)
- `cddr` gets the tail of the tail (everything except the first and second elements in a list)
- `caddr` gets the head of the tail of the tail (the third element in a list)
- and so on ...

We can write this easily using our `car` and `cdr` helpers

```
(define (swap xs)
  (cons (caddr xs)                  ; cons the third element ...
        (cons (cadr xs)             ; onto the second element ...
              (cons (car xs)        ; onto the first element ...
                    (cdddr xs)))))  ; onto the tail of the third element

(swap '(1 2 3))         ; '(3 2 1)
(swap '(1 2 3 4))       ; '(3 2 1 4)
(swap '((1 2) (3) (4))) ; '((4) (3) (1 2))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(define nth 
  ;; Return nth element of list
  (lambda (lst n)
    (cond ((null? lst) 'nil)
          ((zero? n)   (car lst))
          (else (nth (cdr lst) (- n 1))))))

(define slice
  ;; Return lst sliced like python
  (lambda (lst a b acc)
    (cond ((null? lst) (reverse acc))
          ((< b a) (reverse acc))
          ((zero? b) (reverse acc))
          ((zero? a) (slice (cdr lst) 0 (- b 1) (cons (car lst) acc)))
          (else (slice (cdr lst) (- a 1) (- b 1) acc)))))

(define swap
  ;; Return nth and mth element swapped list
  (lambda (lst n m)
    `(,@(slice lst 0 n '()) 
      ,(nth lst m)
      ,@(slice lst (+ n 1)  m '())
      ,(nth lst n)
      ,@(slice lst (+ m 1) (length lst) '()))))
```

This swaps any two given positions m and n and returns the resulting list.

```
(swap your-list 0 2) ; returns your-list 1st and 3rd elements swapped
```